# How to type generic "strategy" pattern?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given these models, I am trying to implement a strategy pattern where using a map, you would be able to invoke a function based on the appropriate key.

I am having trouble getting TS compile with appropriate types

```
enum MyType {
    CHILD_X = "CHILD_X",
    CHILD_Y = "CHILD_Y"
}

abstract class ParentObject {
    readonly type: MyType;
    p: number;
    constructor(type: MyType, p: number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.p = p;
    } 

    public abstract returnMyself(): ParentObject;
}

class ChildXObject extends ParentObject {
    x: string;
    constructor(p: number, x: string) {
        super(MyType.CHILD_X, p);
        this.x = x;
    } 

    public returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}

class ChildYObject extends ParentObject {
    y: string;
    constructor(p: number, y: string) {
        super(MyType.CHILD_Y, p);
        this.y = y;
    } 

    public returnMyself(): ChildYObject {
        return this;
    }
}
```

How would one change it such that I could achieve something like the below?

Attempt 1:

```
type PrintTypeToClass = {
    CHILD_X: ChildXObject
    CHILD_Y: ChildYObject
}

const RENDERERS: {[key in MyType]: (p: PrintTypeToClass[key]) => void} = {
    [MyType.CHILD_X]: function(x: ChildXObject): void {
        console.log(x.p);
        console.log(x.x);
    },
    [MyType.CHILD_Y]: function(y: ChildYObject): void {
        console.log(y.p);
        console.log(y.y);
    }
};

type Objs = ChildXObject | ChildYObject
const listOfObjects: Objs[] = [
    new ChildXObject(0, ""),
    new ChildYObject(0, "")
];

listOfObjects.map(obj => {
    const fn = RENDERERS[obj.type];
    fn(obj); // Argument of type 'Objs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChildXObject & ChildYObject'.
})
```

Attempt 2:

```
const RENDERERS: {[key in MyType]: <T extends ParentObject>(p: T) => void} = {
    // Type of computed property's value is '<T extends ParentObject>(x: ChildXObject) => void', which is not assignable to type '<T extends ParentObject>(p: T) => void'.
    [MyType.CHILD_X]: function(x: ChildXObject): void {
        console.log(x.p);
        console.log(x.x);
    },
    [MyType.CHILD_Y]: function(y: ChildYObject): void {
        console.log(y.p);
        console.log(y.y);
    }
};

const listOfObjects: ParentObject[] = [
    new ChildXObject(0, ""),
    new ChildYObject(0, "")
];

listOfObjects.map(obj => {
    const fn = RENDERERS[obj.type];
    fn(obj);
})
```

Comment: @jcalz Perfect, thank you! This works.

I am only confused about how the distributive conditional type works. Could you kindly explain what the following line is doing?

type Obj<K extends MyType = MyType> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & PrintTypeToClass[P] }[K]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work, the compiler needs to understand that the type of `RENDERERS[obj.type]` is *correlated* to the type of `obj` in just such a way that the former is seen as a function that accepts the latter.  But in your code, both of those are just [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types); the first is a union of functions, and the latter is a union of object types, and the compiler has completely lost track of any relationship between them.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The recommended approach in situations like this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It involves refactoring your operations to be described in terms of some "basic" key-value mapping interfaces, and [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) these types, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over these types.  The GitHub issue goes into detail about the techniques and how they work.  I will show how to apply these techniques to your example.

---

First, we need the compiler to know that a `ChildXObject` has a `type` property of type `MyType.CHILD_X` specifically, and not just `MyType` as inherited from the superclass. We can use a [`declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) to express that the `ChildXObject` subclass is narrowing the type of `type` from that of the superclass:

```
class ChildXObject extends ParentObject {
    declare readonly type: MyType.CHILD_X // <--
    x: string;
    constructor(p: number, x: string) {
        super(MyType.CHILD_X, p);
        this.x = x;
    }    
    public returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the same for `ChildYObject`:

```
class ChildYObject extends ParentObject {
    declare readonly type: MyType.CHILD_Y // <--
    y: string;
    constructor(p: number, y: string) {
        super(MyType.CHILD_Y, p);
        this.y = y;
    }    
    public returnMyself(): ChildYObject {
        return this;
    }
}

type Objs = ChildXObject | ChildYObject;
```

Once we do this, we can use your `Objs` type to *compute* `PrintTypeToClass`, using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

```
type PrintTypeToClass = {
    [T in Objs as T["type"]]: T
}
```

So `PrintTypeToClass` is our basic mapping type.  Now I'm going to define a utility type called `Obj<K>`, of a so-called "distributive object type" as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.  The point is that `Obj<MyType.CHILD_X>` should be essentially equivalent to `ChildXObject`, and that `Obj<MyType.CHILD_Y>` should be essentially equivalent to `ChildYObject`, and that if you pass in the union `Obj<MyType>` which is `Obj<MyType.CHILD_X | MyType.CHILD_Y>`, it will become the union output type equivalent to `ChildXObject | ChildYObject`.  It looks like this:

```
type Obj<K extends MyType = MyType> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & PrintTypeToClass[P] }[K]
```

Note the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` is what does makes it *distributive*.  If `K` is a union of the form `K1 | K2 | K3`, then the output will be a union of the form `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.

Also note the explicit [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `{type: P}` with `PrintTypeToClass[P]`.  This is important because it will be needed to lead the compiler through the logical steps necessary to see the connection between `Obj<K>` and the `type` property.

And finally note that `Obj` by itself is equivalent to `Obj<MyType>` which is essentially the same as just your `Objs`.

---

Now we can write `RENDERERS` the same way you have in one of your attempts:

```
const RENDERERS: { [K in MyType]: (p: PrintTypeToClass[K]) => void } = {
    [MyType.CHILD_X]: function (x: ChildXObject): void {
        console.log(x.p);
        console.log(x.x);
    },
    [MyType.CHILD_Y]: function (y: ChildYObject): void {
        console.log(y.p);
        console.log(y.y);
    }
};
```

and your `listOfObjects` can either be of type `Objs[]` as you had it, or of type `Obj[]`:

```
const listOfObjects: Obj[] = [
    new ChildXObject(0, ""),
    new ChildYObject(0, "")
];
```

And now for the final step: calling the [`map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `listOfObjects`:

```
listOfObjects.map(<K extends MyType>(obj: Obj<K>) => {
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ generic
    const type: K = obj.type; // explicit widening to `K`.
    const fn = RENDERERS[type];
    fn(obj); // okay
})
```

It is very important that the callback function be generic in `K extends MyType`, and that `obj` is of type `Obj<K>`.  This allows the compiler to see the function as acting on a single as-yet-unspecified type `K` instead of a union `MyType`.

It is also important that we explicitly widen `obj.type` to the generic type `K`.  Since `obj` is of type `Obj<K>`, which is equivalent to `{type: K} & PrintTypeToClass[K]`, if we just used `obj.type` it would be inferred from both sides of the intersection to something like `K & MyType`.  This is true, but it messes up the compiler's ability to see the logic.  We need to index with the generic `K`, not with the intersection `K & MyType`.  So `type` is of type `K`.

Then `fn` is seen as type `typeof RENDERERS[K]`, which becomes the single generic function type `(p: PrintTypeToClass[K]) => void`.  This is not a union of functions, but a single function.  And since `obj` is of type `{type: K} & PrintTypeToClass[K]`, the function `fn` will accept it.  (We could widen `obj` to just `PrintTypeToClass[K]` but it's not necessary).

And thus `fn(obj)` compiles.

---

So that's about as type safe as we can get, and we don't need to change your runtime code much, just the form of the types we use to represent them. (If you really wanted we could use `const fn = RENDERERS[obj.type satisfies K as K]` which would leave your runtime code completely unchanged while still having type safety, but I think a slight change with an intermediate `type` variable is more instructive so I introduced it.) And really, it's mostly the *form* of the types that have changed, not what their structures.  The types are the same as before, but now the compiler can see the generic relationship between `RENDERERS[obj.type]` and `obj`.

---

And finally, if you don't care about compiler-verified type safety and only want to make the error go away, you can just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `fn` is a single function type that accepts `obj`:

```
listOfObjects.map(obj => {
    const fn = RENDERERS[obj.type] as (p: typeof obj) => void; // assert
    fn(obj);
})
```

this assertion is technically incorrect, because since `obj` is of the union type `Objs`, then the compiler would not only accept `fn(obj)`, but also `fn(listOfObjects[Math.random()<0.5 ? 0 : 1])`.  The correlation is still not represented with the assertion, it's just that it errs on the side of allowing some unsafe things instead of the side of preventing some safe things.

But what it lacks in correctness it might make up in ease of use.  After all, it's a single line change whereas the approach from microsoft/TypeScript#47109 is more substantial.  It's up to you, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2FA3gWAFBT1AYQAkBJAGQBEB9ADSgF4oAiY86mpgGh30NMqoBNBs1YDBTHAF8cOAIYAjAM4AXAE5yAxiqiaANnKVKoABTlrQKgPIKAVsG0Ye+C3IAmAexB64UFSmAALlhEAIBuZzxkYPAIBWA1CNx8TS9VNTBtDzUACn9UYPgkVE4oaKhY+LUASidk3jwVAAsASyUAOny0Ri6khvxmtvbkEWQ+-BlsSLKwBT0WzShFdK0dCxUwNRB4JWA9ADMc6uCzCxBrOwcVJMmcfUNjAla9Nxobe0dgAA8VUDdjU6Wd5XOq8NwOAwWKCuTzeXxdQqhVDtMTsKAAenRUAAPABaXEVYDANx+Dx+PZ6PxNNCpCDIFp6BJLBQeMA6QZKaZfYLpFogADm4zwqRA6UyKmyOXKlQSpW5UF5AtqWHqDSUYFQuSKARR-HYpWQ1SFDQ57S+Ii+xtuquQs3mi3Wm22cF2ByOoP60OAGy2VLaVuksmw9yMhGebkEwM+Pz+APMQMujhVYIh8a97i8Pj8AURxWAurYQgxWLxBJARJJEvJekpzRpHjpDKZilZ7NanNVcB56j5gumIrFWVy0sgVVKXYVPaVHv66s1OW1yNRQgNRumvFNvkYcADUxtdoWXp9ztdh2OYYZEajOmTnsdvo5u+tXSg72MjCel7eiZ0AB8Ly8kY-kkmJevsqzZKSugNraaAclA+xqA2r52B2OAviYah8ioeYIB4BAGKGjC3ngADaCBQHyKG2MYhhQAgpFMF0TAALoscECCBnuoHlsSfrGG4bQ9gobItAAbmgHg-tmqDoQE1HYgA0lA3y-CA-whHmIiLsAAB8DDTOgUCkSYlEgFAinsRgMlBKYUBSFAABkphYecuH4YRSgmSx9mkZZOCgZ6-QAHqhWF4XBVAEBgKoUDxCpXzIPaLQ6C2bL8UGPEeL8VJyDo7xQAA7ilTStksUD8qACSHi+5j8pAliUcYwAAI5gOJciMucUFvnJqD0cAsWMO8IFYngwUAPxBgOOgAEoAKIAHIUPNC2zQAysERl+WZmkBFZUonK5OEBHhBEPH5LG1PQ+liR4LQkg5xHTKROkFgINBWfsYAgNoLReFAOTyp+Lzfh8KjnndD0zg0A4eIy7R6B4-JA8Ma6qrwcMI0jKNfGa6O8FI3Cqq9SL5sughfT9f0AzkE4g1eP6Q-dJIkbDaTw-mON02jxqYxz2PIzzcAExM0hJHcaQ6PMqhWPs15KMEb6kT5jCkdM5aFQBrzXjkAAMpRMEw1TE7wmva0B4P64bxs4CxEvYDL1jyz+HQQHIyA5EpCVqRpOm6TkUm2ErdhKbp136WzgVBeNEVxxFUUxTo8WVeWWGaP2Us2cEymMEHnThMWiexfF3xJQsKXMmVHKZ6KOj7OZjALctq2retpFdPb0wN4HdhGkXHgANZyHA0jVEGIByBAg3IFoaAAIJGAkN7TBhx3uedREw7wy40MEDNg1c674BT+-hpbR+qta-N11AzcrWtm3WaRg-AL4VE6Qd5SYdhG+eS-b8roMFuizeyIg2a8FJnmd67Aqa-RUP9cyQMz5fmvMzaGEDPRYy5kLPGho+ZYIFjg3G+MCF4CJsfMib0KZwJpkg+m580HBChqzSh7NRSc0RkLOAvM2E3yUJw7mPCRZkPstMKQDsNzyTfCIA+14oD-gZhfbQtdYpOzlgrEONEVYiHVhjfA5s5E-mtswY2ptPSGMYcYg2pjx6qi7nuXg6iXbgzdh7XuthgHbxSFnBuIh76tw2qRfOncljGEOjZDw+woBBwjlAFhYQi4PGXmwnusSrR2KkEAA)